# Making footer stay at bottom with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, footer, sticky-footer

I'm trying to make footer stay at bottom. I'v searched through Google, but with no luck with the code I have. I've tried `navbar-fixed-bottom`, but that just makes the footer content scroll beneath it, and it stays fixed which I don't want.

Here is the current code I have:

**HTML**

```
        <footer>
          <div class="container">
            <p class="text-p"><img src="images/footer-logo.png"> © 2015 <a href="http://www.domainname.no">Domainname.no</a>. All rights reserved.
            <!--<a href="https://www.facebook.com/Helsespesialisten-448789105236638/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>Follow us on Facebook</a>-->
          </div>
        </footer>
```

**CSS**

```
            footer {
              position: absolute;
              bottom: 0;
              width: 100%;
              /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
              height: 60px;
              background-color: #f5f5f5;
            }

            .text-p{
                text-shadow: none;
                font-size: 14px;
                color: #999;
                padding: 20px 0 0 5px;
            }
```

I would appreciate any help! Let me know if you need rest of the code.

Comment: use "position:fixed"

Comment: Always do a search before asking questions

Comment: @LaljiTadhani I don't want it to be fixed, as mentioned in post. I've tried `navbar-fixed-bottom`

Comment: www.cssreset.com/demos/layouts/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

Comment: @LaljiTadhani link is broken

Comment: It was easier to find the actual link instead of moaning about it. Collaboration is the name of the game. https://cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there, the one thing it lacks is setting the parent with a relative position:

```
body {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

And then you can make sure that it stays always there by adding a negative value to bottom. E.g.:

```
footer {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    bottom: -100px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Btw, you don't need to add margins to the `<body>`, since all the content is in it :)

### Edit

After reviewing a while, the solution above would be enough if bigger screens with higher heights were not considered...

The problem was that the middle container itself didn't fill the entire space, making the footer appear in the middle.

Therefore, instead of using `position: absolute` or `fixed` for the footer (or even to the `<body>`), the solution was to adjust the height of that same middle container to the height of the window by this:

```
<script>
  $('body>.container').height(
    $(window).height()-
    $('body>.container-fluid').height()-
    $('body>footer').height()
  );
</script>
```

Setting the middle container's to the window's height removing the upper container's and footer's height places the footer in the correct position.

Also for the footer itself this rule comes in handy: `footer{overflow: hidden}`, just in case the contents/inner spacings of the footer overflow it.

Comment: Exactly, what I was looking for! :) Thanks!

Comment: On Firefox the footer looks fine, but on Chrome and Safari it doesn't. Is there any way I can style for Chrome so it stays at bottom?

Comment: Please view this link: http://prntscr.com/8u279i This is on Chrome. Will this fix the problem by changing to `10px 0 0 5px` and `overflow: hidden` ?

Comment: I tried adding `overflow: hidden`, but still the footer isnt at the bottom on Chrome and Safari, its kind of in the middle. You can check it with the link in post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93077/discussion-between-armfoot-and-nohmanj).

Answer (score 1):

There's a HOWTO on the getbootstrap.com site, in the getting started section:
http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Comment: He doesn't want a sticky footer, he just wants the footer to stay at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Armfoot - that would be the definition of a sticky footer, wouldn't it?

Comment: @MrMarlow I would agree with you but the sticky plugins I used before actually sticked the elements with `position: fixed`, the OP's goal was to avoid that. Matthew's link though seems to use only `position:absolute` after inspecting...